# Lightful globe smart bulb

Tags: lighting, smart-lights

I have just bought this model of floor lamp:

https://www.maisonsdumonde.com/ES/es/p/lampara-con-tripode-de-metal-negro-alt-180-making-of-165180.htm

As you can see, there's a glass in front of where the light bulb is located, also the light bulb goes inside vertically aligned to the floor, so does not project the light to the glass directly:

[image]

So I've thought about buying a globe bulb. The problem is that I would like it to be smart and currently I'm using a standard LED bulb which is 1400 lm and results in very little lighting:

[image]

I would like something about 2000 lm at least in the globe format, but does anybody know if there's something like this in the market? The most powerful smart bulbs I've found are around 1000 lm.

Comment: You may be able to get creative with some smart rgb led strings spiraled inside of your housing. I can't comment on the lumens, I haven't even seen any of them listed with that information. They are pretty bright though.

Comment: use a smart plug instead of a smart bulb

Comment: Is the interior of the lamp all black like it looks like on the picture? You could probably gain quite a bit of illumination by coating the interior of the lamp with foil (aluminium) or even just some white material or paint. A lot of the light is probably just absorbed by the black material.

Comment: @jsotola the point of the smart bulb is I want to choose the light intensity too, depending on the moment.

Comment: @XtremeBiker some smart plugs have a dimmer function